# EnumDisplaySettings maximum mode number

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

How do you determine the maximum number of display modes returnable by EnumDisplaySettings without incrementing the second parameter until the function fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN's Documentation on [EnumDisplaySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It looks like your only option is to increment `IModeNum`

From Link:

> Graphics mode indexes start at zero. To obtain information for all of a display device's graphics modes, make a series of calls to EnumDisplaySettings, as follows: Set iModeNum to zero for the first call, and increment iModeNum by one for each subsequent call. Continue calling the function until the return value is zero.